# How to use Jekyll and Github Pages to build personal website

Tags: git, jekyll, github-pages

I followed all of the steps displayed on this tutorial offered by Github in this site:[enter link description here](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/#setting-up-jekyll)but when I came to the 'Running Jekyll' column,I happened to a error message shows "fatal:you are on a branch yet to be born" when I ran the command:git checkout.

Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you just created the repo. Try committing something first, since the master branch is not yet created. Only after the first commit you will have a master branch that you will be able to checkout.